# Swift - Write/Read gif file to/from IOS directory

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, gif, nsfilemanager

I am creating an application that shows gifs from giphy.com in UICollectionView.

I am using dedicated framework **Giphy-iOS** to load gifs and **SwiftGifOrigin** to create gifs from loaded data. I am storing gif's data in Documents directory for offline mode using:

```
lazy var documentsPath: URL = {
    return try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
}()

lazy var gifsPath: URL = {
    let path = self.documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("gifs")
    try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: path, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
    return path
}()

func save(data: Data, named: String) {
    let path = gifsPath.appendingPathComponent(named)
    (data as NSData).write(to: path, atomically: true)
}
```

But reading data (or converting into gif) takes a lot of memory and slow down app performance, despite the fact that the operation is performed in background queue.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let image = UIImage.gif(url: someExistingPath)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            imageView.image = image
        }
    }
```

I was trying to read data from directory and than convert to gif, but got the same effect. When I obtain storing method, app works smoothly, so there is no issue with data loading.

What can cause short freezing even in background queue? How can I store gifs to the app folder for offline purposes in right way? Or how can I read data and create gifs without freezing?

Also, I reduce amount of gifs to 2 on screen at one time, but app is still glitchy.

Comment: If you are calling save() on the main thread, then that could be slowing you down.  Dispatch that to the background.  Honestly your best bet is to run Instruments and see what is slow.  It will tell you what is consuming CPU and what is holding onto the main thread.

Comment: @DavidShaw Thanks, but I check it twice, it is not in main queue. Anyway, app is slowing on reading, not writing. My best guess is RAM consumptions for gif creation. And I do not know how to fix it.